# Adding UIActivityindicatorView in an UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

I want to create a UIAlertView that will say that "...in progress". It will also show that UIActivityindicatorView on it. Could you let me know how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Its pretty simple. Just create a UIActivityIndicatorView and add it as a subview to the UIAlertView.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" " message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
    progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    [alert addSubview:progress];
    [progress startAnimating];

    [alert show];
```

Comment: It's great answer but i'm wondering how can i dismiss it from the view if there is no button ?

Comment: [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

Comment: isn't that prohibited by Apple ? (Adding subviews to UIAlertView)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It doesn't use any private APIs. While quite some time ago, I've had this bit of code approved before.

Comment: for iOS7, adding subview to UIAlertView is not possible! reference [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759206/how-to-add-subview-inside-uialertview-for-ios-7)

Answer (score 2):

In my case i found what using hardcoded frame origins it's bad. And if my message has more one line, indicator showing top of my message.

So i create function with layouting indicator if size UIAlertView

```
+(UIAlertView*) progressAlertWithTitle:(NSString*) title andMessage:(NSString*) message andDelegate:(id)delegate{
    UIAlertView *progressAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [progressAlert setTitle:title];
    [progressAlert setMessage:message];
    [progressAlert setDelegate:delegate];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *progress=nil;
    progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    [progressAlert addSubview:progress];
    [progress startAnimating];

    [progressAlert show];

    progress.frame=CGRectMake(progressAlert.frame.size.width/2-progress.frame.size.width, progressAlert.frame.size.height-progress.frame.size.height*2, progress.frame.size.width, progress.frame.size.height);


    return progressAlert;
}
```

In this case, indicator always by center

**One line message:**

[image]

**More one line message:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView   *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.center = CGRectMake(xcords, ycords, width, height);
[alert addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startanimating];
[alert show];
```

This spinner gets hidden on dismiss of AlertView.

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```