# How to Add a UIDatePicker to UIALertView in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker, uialertview, ios7

I have implemented datepicker in one of my view, 
The way is added the datepicker to the Alertview. Now in iOS 7 i am not able to find the datepicker on the alertview, When searched i have got, we cannot add anything to alertview in iOS7.

My requirement was When i will select the DOB textfield, I have to show the Datepickerview and modify the date and the changed value will be stored into the textfield.

Now my problem is How can i show the datepicker on the alertview.

I have tried showing on the view, but when trying to remove the datpicker from view it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but I believe the following allows what the OP requested and I don't think will violate Apple's rules involving AlertView hierarchy changes:

```
- (void)requestDateOfBirth
{
UIDatePicker *birthDatePicker;
UIAlertView *setBirthDate;
NSDateFormatter *birthDateFormatter;
UITextField *birthDateInput;
//create the alertview
setBirthDate = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date of Birth:"
                                              message:nil
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
setBirthDate.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

//create the datepicker
birthDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[birthDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
birthDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;    
birthDatePicker.date = [NSDate date];
//get the textfield provided in the plain text alertview
birthDateInput = [setBirthDate textFieldAtIndex:0];
//change the textfields inputView to the date picker
birthDateInput.inputView = birthDatePicker;
[birthDateInput setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
//create a date formatter to suitably show the date
birthDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[birthDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
//set the current date into the textfield
birthDateInput.text = [birthDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
//show the alert view and activate the textfield
[setBirthDate show];
[birthDateInput becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Then don't forget the handle the changes in the date picker

```
- (void) dateChanged:(id)sender
{
NSDateFormatter *birthDateFormatter;
UIDatePicker *birthDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;

birthDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[birthDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
birthDateInput.text = [birthDateFormatter stringFromDate:birthDatePicker.date];
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 you can use

```
[alertView setValue:yourDataPicker forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Full explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067447/2066428)

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy of `UIAlertView` is private and should not be modified.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Until iOS 6, you could add some views to the `UIAlertView` subviews hierarchy, but this doesn’t seems to work anymore on iOS 7. The `contentView` property that was announced for iOS7 was made a private ivar since beta4 release, thus making it impossible to `addSubview` to alert view.

```
UIView *_contentViewNeue;
```

For more on this refer this [Apple dev forum discussion](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/196613?tstart=0) (You will need to login)

In such situations, you should create a custom view mimicking the `UIAlertView` and then use that to add the picker view.

Hope that helps!