# Add UILabel Inside UIAlertView in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uilabel, uialertview, subview

I am want to add UILabel inside UIAlertView in IOS7. My Code is working fine in iOS7 less versions.

Comment: Did you even try to search? There is more than 10 answers declaring that there is no more addSubView in UIAlertView in iOS7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)

Comment: I try to search, But there is a little confusion i.e. there is a way to add UITextField into UIAlertView in iOS. So, due to this i wanna get confirmation. Because i have to add UILabel into UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AddSubview is not possible from iOS 7.

[How to add subview inside UIAlertView for iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759206/how-to-add-subview-inside-uialertview-for-ios-7/19004139#19004139)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 you can use

```
[alertView setValue:customContentView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Full explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067447/2066428)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.