# customised alert view for asking user comments and rates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

i want to do something like this : i want to prompt an alert view,but inside that alert view i want to add some labels,text fields and star marks[for rating].how can i do that in iOS.i am using iOS 7.and i am really new to this.i did this in my android application. but i don't know how to do that same thing in here.

in my application i am using storyboards.i had an idea about to design a customised view and load it inside alert view. but i do not know weather that can be done or not.please someone help me for this.

thank you.

Comment: Search github / cocoacontrols for a solution

Comment: check out this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759206/how-to-add-subview-inside-uialertview-for-ios-7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759206/how-to-add-subview-inside-uialertview-for-ios-7) but don't know if apple accept this or not.

Comment: Try this
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)

Comment: no guys... none of worked for me

Answer (score 1):

- Any CustomView can't be directly added to UIALertView.
- For alertView there is one property "accesseryView".By Using this we can add any UIView  to UIAlertView.

  > -(void)customAlertView{
  >
  > ```
  > UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"your Title" message:@"Your
  > ```
  >
  > Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Your
  >   Button Title" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  >
  > ```
  > NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomViewOnAlert"  owner:self options:nil];
  > MyCustomViewOnAlert *myView = (MyCustomViewOnAlert*) [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
  >
  > [Alert setValue:myView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
  >
  > [Alert show];
  > ```
  >
  > }
- One Custom View "MyCustomViewOnAlert" is created on XIB.

Try This

Comment: im really a beginner, so can you tell me that since i am using storyboards is it ok if i am use a different xib for this? this might be a silly question. but i really do not now that.

Comment: Yeah .It will work .It will not affect your storyBorad.Try this and let me know if you are getting anything wrong .Gud Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you need library prompting user to rate your app in the App Store use this library
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate