# Adding subview on UIAlertView for iOS7

Tags: uialertview

In iOS 7 the `[alert addSubview];` method is not working for adding any subview on the alert view.

So I used `[alert setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];` to display the **UIActivityIndicator** on the alert view.

My questions are:

1. Is `@"accessoryView"` public to the API to add the view on alert ?
2. Will apple accept this type of behaviour ?

Comment: Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21067447/208623

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add subview inside UIAlertView for iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759206/how-to-add-subview-inside-uialertview-for-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

You **SHOULD NOT** be adding views to a `UIAlertView` this is a one fast track ticket to getting your app rejected from the App Store, check out the section mark as **Subclassing Notes** from the [Apple `UIAlertView` Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

In iOS7 Apple basically re-enforced the above by making it so `addSubview:` actually did nothing, it is there still though because `UIAlertView` is a subclass of `UIView` and `UIView` can still respond to this method. Many have however written custom AlertViews check out [iOS Custom AlertView](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) for example