# Image in alertview is not working in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I used the follwing code to add image in alert view. But its not working.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Popup" message:@"popup" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

UIImageView *tempImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gg.jpg"]];

tempImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

tempImg.frame = CGRectMake(90, 40, 100, 120);

//    tempImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gg.jpg"];

[alert addSubview:tempImg];

[alert show];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: With iOS7, Apple removed this feature of attaching a subview to a standard UIAlertView. For custom UIAlertView see the link --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7

Comment: In ios7 you need to add subview in a way desribed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21067447/2066428

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `addSubview` to a UIAlertView from iOS 7. You have to make your own alertView if you want to customize it. There are also lots of custom alertview available on net. You may try this **[one](http://www.wimagguc.com/2013/10/custom-ios7-uialertview/)**.